# limit of a two variables exponential function

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

This is my problem today.

> Consider the function
>
> $$ f(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}
>      e^{\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}} & \mbox{se} & x^2+y^2<1 \\
>      0 & \mbox{se} & x^2+y^2\geq1 \end{array} \right. $$
>
> Compute
>   $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}
> \dfrac{f(x,y)}{x^2+y^2-1}$.

For $x^2+y^2<1$, I can write

$$\frac{e^{\lim\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}}}{\lim (x^2+y^2-1)} =\frac{0}{\lim (x^2+y^2-1)}=0, $$

since $\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}\rightarrow-\infty$

[image]

Comment: I don't think the problem satisfies the assumptions needed to apply l'hopitals rule (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule).

Comment: oh... you're right, so I have to compute $\lim 1/(x^2+y^2-1) =1/0$... so lateral limits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we note that $$\lim_{\ a\rightarrow \ -\infty}\ e^aa=0$$
next we note $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}
\dfrac{e^{(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1})}}{x^2+y^2-1}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}
e^{(g(x,y))}g(x,y)$

where $g(x,y)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+y^2-1}$

as $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}g(x,y)\rightarrow-\infty$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}
e^{(g(x,y))}g(x,y)=\lim_{\ a\rightarrow \ -\infty}\ e^aa=0$$

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)\ }
\dfrac{f(x,y)}{x^2+y^2-1}=\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)}
\dfrac{e^{(\frac{1}{x^2+y^2-1})}}{x^2+y^2-1}=0$$

when $(x,y)$ approaches $\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right)$ from inside the circle

Comment: Do I need to consider from outside too?

Comment: from outside the limit is zero as well as $f(x,y)=0$ for all points outside and hence $f(x,y)\times g(x,y)= 0\times g(x,y)=0$